# Unable to open LiClipse 6.1.0 on MacOS/Catalina (10.15.3)

Tags: installation, macos-catalina, liclipse

I have downloaded LiClipse 6.1.0 from http://www.liclipse.com/download.html three times (to ensure that I don't have a corrupt/damaged file) and installed it on a MacPro Notebook with MacOS Catalina (10.15.3). I have followed the installation instructions at http://www.liclipse.com/download.html for Native Mac OS Install, but every time I get "“LiClipse.app” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash."

Since it gets installed without any problem, I think that downloaded file is not corrupted/damaged, but when opening it I always get the warning about its being damaged even when I have run `sudo spctl --master-disable` to enable apps from "Anywhere" to run.
I would appreciate if anyone who had succeeded in opening it on a MacPro/Catalina would share his/her steps. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can try removing the quarantine flag (when Mac downloads a file it marks it as quarantined and it won't run unless it has an Apple signature -- which LiClipse doesn't have, so, Apple is making it always a bit harder to run files you download).

To remove the quarantine flag, run:

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine <FILE>`

(`<FILE>` being `/Applications/LiClipse.app` and maybe `/Applications/LiClipse.app/MacOS/LiClipse` too -- I don't really have Catalina to check).

Comment: Thanks much, Fabio. Your solution worked like a charm! Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Fabio. The second <FILE> on Catalina is /Applications/LiClipse.app/Contents/MacOS/LiClipse